# export mysql to xls using php (browser issue)

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export

ok there is a few issues when i downloaded it using mozila firefox, name of file is just "report" and without .xls . so i must click the openwith first to open the file. but this issue is not happen when i run it in chrome.

mozila : report
chrome : report 29-08-2014 dailymeal.xls

can you help me to tell what is wrong in my code ? thanks in advance

here is the code :

```
<?php



$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('qrgad',$con);


$tanggal_awal=$_POST['tanggal_awal'];
$tanggal_akhir=$_POST['tanggal_akhir'];
$today= date ("Y-m-d");
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$db_name = "qrgad"; 
$tbl_name =$_POST['report'];


if($tbl_name=="dailymeal")
 {$query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where date>='$tanggal_awal' and date <='$tanggal_akhir'"; }
if($tbl_name=="infomeal")
{ $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where tanggal >='$tanggal_awal' and tanggal <='$tanggal_akhir'"; }
if($tbl_name=="keluhan")
{ $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where tlapor >='$tanggal_awal' and tlapor <='$tanggal_akhir'"; }
if($tbl_name=="perjalanan")
{ $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where request_date>='$tanggal_awal' and request_date <='$tanggal_akhir'"; }
if($tbl_name=="tamu")
{ $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where jam_masuk>='$tanggal_awal' and jam_masuk <='$tanggal_akhir'"; }
if($tbl_name=="tiket")
{ $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where waktu_input>='$tanggal_awal' and waktu_input <='$tanggal_akhir'"; }
if($tbl_name=="trx_kons")
{ $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where date_trx>='$tanggal_awal' and date_trx <='$tanggal_akhir'"; }
if($tbl_name=="uniform")
{ $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where reqtime >='$tanggal_awal' and reqtime <='$tanggal_akhir'"; }
if($tbl_name=="sewa")
{ $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where waktu_input >='$tanggal_awal' and waktu_input <='$tanggal_akhir'"; }
if($tbl_name=="komunikasi")
{ $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where waktu_input >='$tanggal_awal' and waktu_input <='$tanggal_akhir'"; }
if($tbl_name=="konsumable")
{ $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name"; }

$header = '';
$data ='';
$export = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );


$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
}


while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\nNo Record(s) Found!\n";                        
}


header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$today." Report ".$tbl_name.".xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";

?>
```

Comment: [**Errors, checking for them?**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) - What is wrong, I don't understand the question. Please be more specific.

Comment: sorry my english so bad. ok maybe like this. i have a problem when i download excel report from DB using mozila firefox. the format file is not attached on the file. so just like thiss : Report. but when i try to download excel report using chrome, the result is no problem. report.xls . can you undertand?

Comment: It's not your English, it's the question. You need to tell us what is wrong and what the expected results are to be. You need to check for errors also, as my link above. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything/errors. That will help troubleshoot.

Comment: Ok, I re-read your question and understand what you mean now. Still, add error reporting, see what errors you get, just in case. That should be the first step when debugging code.

Comment: looks like a csv file to me, its certainly not xls

Comment: no error guys, and still download the report without extension

Comment: When you open the file, is there indeed data inside it? See this link also http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php you seem to be missing a few parts in your headers.

Comment: yes, the data is good. the problem is just when i download using mozila firefox or IE, the file downloaded without extension

Comment: @kafi Consult my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line: (it's the quotes) see `^ here and ^ here` under the first line of code below.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$today." Report ".$tbl_name.".xls");
                                                           ^ here   ^ and here
```

to either (and by removing the quotes)

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$today.Report.$tbl_name.".xls");
```

or

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$today.'_' .Report.'_'.$tbl_name.".xls");
```

The last one will put an underscore between each name/word.

---

Edit: as per OP's comment

> *thanks guys, it's resolved. the problem is header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); and that should be header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;"); and thanks for the filename issues*

Comment: thanks guys, it's resolved. the problem  is header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); and that should be header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;"); and thanks for the filename issues :)

Comment: @kafi Great, glad to hear it's been resolved, *cheers* I will add your comment under my answer.

Comment: @kafi Yet,when I tested it with as much as I could, it did not give the `.xls` option with your code, but did with mine, just saying in case that was a contributing factor. :)

Comment: yes, it is not header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); , but header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;"); am i right?

Comment: @kafi I tend to think that both should work. If you've tried both, stick with the one you want, yet `application/vnd.ms-excel` could be better.

Comment: @kafi Stick with that then :)

Comment: you know its not actully an xls file type

Comment: it will work while what ever he uses ignores the fact its not actully what he says it is, will it work for every one else? will it work for the next or previous excel versions?

Comment: if you know just call it *.csv